# Dynamic proxy_pass depending on the API response

Tags: nginx, webserver

We operate a SaaS service that enables users to deploy web service containers. We previously needed to set up another web server, but doing so causes issues because our web server has limitations that prevent the use of WebSockets. We are considering using NGINX to achieve this, but we're not sure of the best way to proceed. Our API endpoint provides the IP and port of a specific host using the following URL:

```
http://localhost:5555/check?host={host}
```

where response is like:

```
127.0.0.1:43435
```

We already tried using ngx_http_js_module to extend our web server config with Javascript.

```js
async function dynamic_proxy(host) {
  ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Dynamic proxy for host: " + host);
  try {
    var res = await ngx.fetch("http://localhost:5555/check?host=" + host);
    var data = await res.json();
    ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Upstream server: " + data.target);
    return data.target;
  } catch (e) {
    return "https://example.com/";
  }
}

export default {
  dynamic_proxy,
};
```

```perl
        location / {
            js_set $endpoint "dynamic_proxy('$server_name')";
            proxy_pass $endpoint;
        }
```

We couldn't get the code above working due to limitations and [lack of async support with js_set](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_js_module.html#js_set) using  the Javascript module.